# How to clear text input box on pressing enter (in a div)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a input box using a div, but I'm having some difficulty finding how to clear the text box upon pressing enter.

I've searched for a solution and have found this code that uses an eventListener and a function.

```js
var messageinputbox = document.createElement("input"); 

messageinputbox.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('chatbox').value = "";
  }
});

document.getElementById("messageinput").appendChild(messageinputbox);
```

The fuction does not work, even though I do not see any syntax errors in it, and my javascript file doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'keydown' or 'keypress' instead of 'keyup'?

Comment: Where is the ID `chatbox`?

Comment: Please try and create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) with enough code for others to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never gave the new input box the ID `chatbox`. You need

```
messageinputbox.id = "chatbox";
```

But there's no need for the ID, since the `messageinputbox` variable holds a reference to the input box. Just use that variable in the function.

```js
var messageinputbox = document.createElement("input"); 

messageinputbox.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    messageinputbox.value = "";
  }
});

document.getElementById("messageinput").appendChild(messageinputbox);
```

```html
<div id="messageinput"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:
     
         `<html>
         <head>
           <title>Javascript key press demo</title>
           <script type='text/javascript'>
             function clearTextonEnterKeyPress(e){
                  if(e.keyCode == 13){
                    alert("You Have Pressed Enter Key.");
                    document.getElementById('test').value = "";
                    alert('Text Cleared');
                   }
             }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          Press Enter Button in text box
          <input type='text' onkeypress='clearTextonEnterKeyPress(event)' id='test'>
         </body>
         </html>`